# Como enviar por parametro un array json_encode de PHP a JS

Tags: php, ajax

Hola a todos los desarrolladores. Tengo una consulta... EHH, estoy haciendo una practica de un CRUD.. y tengo la funcionalidad de agregar y eliminar completada.. ahora me falta colocar los datos del usuario en especifico en un modal.. estoy tratando de colocar el retorno de la consulta en un json_encode y pasar dicho array por parametro en una funcion para ser recibida en JS. pero al invocar esa funcion me da un error de Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input.                    Alguien me podria ayudar con este error de favor..

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

se ve que se estan pasando los datos por parametro en la funcion. pero al hacer lick.. da ese error. Este es el codigo donde se cargan los datos de la base de datos:

```
require_once('muestra.php');
try {
    $db = new Repository();
    $select = $db->Query('SELECT * FROM laptop ORDER BY id ASC');
    foreach ($select as $key) {     
    $datos = json_encode($key);
      echo '<tr>';
      echo '<td>'.'<center>'.$key['id'].'</center>';
      echo '<td>'.$key['marca'].'</center>';
      echo '<td>'.'<center>'.$key['pulgadas'].'</center>';
      echo '<td>'.$key['especificaciones'].'</center>';
      echo '<td>'.$key['precio'].'</center>';
      echo '<td><center><i style="cursor:pointer;" class="fa fa-trash" onclick="delet('.$key['id'].');"></i>'.'&nbsp'.'&nbsp'.'&nbsp'.'&nbsp'.'<i style="cursor:pointer;" class="fa fa-refresh" onclick="addform('.$datos.');" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"></i></center></td>';   
      echo '<tr/>';
    }
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "Se ha producido un error al intentar mostrar los datos". $e->getMessage();
}
```

Aqui el archivo muestra.php :

```
class Repository
{   
function getConnection()
{
  $username = 'root';
  $password = '1RizpPfTeBsqEbku';
  $dsn = 'mysql:dbname=tecno;host=127.0.0.1';
  try {
    $connection = new PDO($dsn,$username,$password);
    $connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    return $connection;
  }
  catch (PDOException $e) {
  echo "Se he producido un Error al intentar conectar al Servidor MySql: ". $e->getMessage();
  }
  function Query($sql)
  {
  try {
  $connection = $this->getConnection();
  $query = $connection->prepare($sql);
  $query->execute();
  return $query;
  } catch (PDOException $e) {
  echo "Se ha producido un error en la Consulta". $e->getMessage(); 
    }
   }        
  }
```

Comment: Estás pidiendo un resultado via ajax al backend usando algo como jQuery?

Comment: Asi es... estoy tratando de recibir ese array en una funcion Jquery.. asi mismo lo hice para capturar el id y el proceso delete

Comment: ya que antes de agregar funcionalidad completa al jquery primero ejecuto un alert de los datos capturados en jquery para verificar que todo va bien.. pero el error esta en el backend.. el la venta development se ven los datos pasador como array both. pero al hacer click la invocacion a la funcion fracasa.

Comment: function addform(data){
      
       alert(data);
      }

Comment: Estás pidiendo una respuesta Json, y desde el back estás devolviendo HTML. Debieras poner simplemente `echo $datos;` y luego debuggear el contenido de la respuesta desde el front. Todo el html de las celdas que hoy tratas de poner desde el backend tienes que ponerlos en tu front.

Comment: interesante.. voy hacer esa prueba unitaria.. pero si te fijas arriba.. el echo alli esta... en la imagen de la ventana development se ve que esta pasando el array por parametro.

Comment: Sí, de estar está, pero está junto con mucho html que lo convierte en un JSON inválido. Basta una coma de sobra para que un json sea imparseable para el front.

Comment: lo probare de otra manera.. pasare ese codigo a la view y pasare el json como  addform('<?php   echo $datos; ?>) a ver como va. Gracias por la sugerencia

Comment: Por favor, añade el código problemático en lugar de capturas de pantalla, las capturas no las podemos copiar en nuestros editores para hacer las pruebas oportunas.

Comment: ok. pasare la clase de la conexion tambien vale

Comment: amenadiel.. ya pase el codigo al front.. y pues me da el mismo error.. seguire proband..

Answer (score 1):

Php envia unas cabeceras con cada salida de datos del server, si esa salida esta compuesta de multiples echo con html y luego un echo de un json, automaticamente seran cabeceras html y la variable en javascript que contenga esa salidad solo tomara como texto su contenido.

Tomando de ejemplo tu codigo

`$ajax.get(url, function(response){
  console.log(response);
});`

Mostraria solo el html en la consola.

Entonces que hacemos? 
Bastaria con definir dos funciones:

- Una para devolver html generado tras la consulta que sera incluido en un div/tabla/elemento de tu pagina gracias a jQuery con innerHTML por ejemplo.
- Otra para devolver la lista de la consulta como JSON.

El problema es que tendrias que hacer dos llamadas, doble trabajo no ?

Y si devuelves solo el JSON y generas el texto de la plantilla con templates strings ?

    `` function obtenerDatos() {
     var misDatos;
     $ajax.get('http://localhost/bla/blabla', function (datosEnJson){
       var plantillaFinal = '';
       $.forEach(datosEnJson, function(dato){
         plantillaFinal+= `
          <tr>
            <td>${dato.propiedad}</td>
          </tr>
         `;
       });
       $('table').html(templateFinal);
       misDatos = datosEnJson;
     })
    } ``